Issue with plt.scatter() in Python due to data that isn't the same size
I'm building the code for a Data Mining assignment currently, and I'm trying to work out how I'm supposed to use this specific kind of data with the plt.scatter command.
enter image description here
This is one of the trial data pieces I have to try and use.
The assignment is to write a K-means code on jupyter notebook. It needs to have an input called TrainData, that includes N lines (which is equal to the amount of data), and M columns. Each line symbolizes one piece of data, and each column is the value of the characteristic. Right now I'm trying to make a basic plot, where X=N(M,S) (I got no idea what the hell S is supposed to be?)
The M portion of the data and the S portion aren't the same size, I can tell one. There's also the fact one is a Matrice and the other just, (4, 0). How the hell am I supposed to make this work?
Trying that again and again just gives me that x and y must be the same size, which I know.
This is the code I'm running to make the plot:
plt.scatter(x , y, marker='o', color='black')
plt.xlabel('Mi')
plt.ylabel('Si')
plt.title('Data Points Before Clustering')
plt.show()

